# Can I commit to another remote branch using tortoise git?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I had a branch A.

Then I created branch B based on A.

I made some local changes in branch B and I understand that I should commit these changes to branch A.

Can make it without switching to branch A ?

Answer (score 0):

A tricky way:

1. Delete A branch
   [image]
2. Rename B branch to A branch
   [image]

perhaps assign tracked branch
[image]